# Passing URL parameters with PHP

Tags: php, md5

I am creating a program that communicates with a PHP script on a web server and to do so I need to be able to pass parameters from the program to the PHP script.

Now here is my question. At some point the user name and password needs to be passed to the script. Now this is not done in a way that is apparent to users (such as in an address bar) but I know with a little sniffing around someone that really wanted to could figure it out. So while my script is safe from injection, obviously variable tampering is an issue here.

This is an idea I have come up with so please help me wrap my head around it and see if this would work the way I THINK it will.

My thought was to encrypt the user password (or another unique key) variables on the client side before sending so you get a url like (obviously just made up) mypage.php?un=Oa348uty8&ps=op986hGTfreu Then when it gets to the PHP script decrypt it and encrypt it again with a different salt.

So when it leaves the application it would be encrypted but not the correct way, and then when it hits the PHP script server side decrypt it and re-encrypt it with the correct salt so it would correctly match the stored encrypted password.

This way, they user would not know what the encrypted version of their password is supposed to look like so without that they would not be able to tamper with the URL and try to insert fake values.

Comment: How is this any different from a _normal_ login situation? If you have encryption available just use it the normal, correct, way.

Comment: when you store the passwords on your server as hash strings - which you should anyway. (like sha256 or something similar) then the best would be to generate the hash client side, and only transmitting the hash to the server. the rest is simple string comparison. no decryption needed.

Comment: The encrypted password given to the URL cannot be decrypted by a human. Nevertheless, it can be re-used as is (i.e. encrypted) by a hacker for another connection.

Comment: What I was trying to avoid is someone being able to manipulate the data. so if the parameters are passed from the application to PHP and someone sniffs the out they can't take those parameters and call the script in a web browser to manipulate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it in a nutshell, you are thinking of this:

On server side you have:

- a database, with login/password matches.
- a script that take 2 parameters (password and username) and check in the database if the couple exists

Your problem:

When your local application call the php script on server side, the 2 parameters are given in plain text. And you want to avoid tampering ( if your script are safe against injection i only see tampering used to bruteforce the auth <= keep in mind that i will keep this assumption in the whole post)

Your solution:

- On client side, encrypt the 2 parameters
- On server side, add a salt in your script to salt
- Then decrypt the 2 parameters and encrypt with a salt

What I think:

This will not solve the tampering issue, someone can still forge requests.
The first encryption is useless because someone can retreive the key used by your client.
The second encryption is not safe enought because you use the same salt for all you users.

What I suggest:

Accept that tampering can't be avoided if you don't use a secure protocol like HTTPS (can either use SSL or TLS).
If you want an acceptable security without HTTPS the following is what i would implement:

- A token system that you will check in order to see if the user can perform the login operation
- A username that would not be encrypted
- The password sha1 hashed stored in database
- On client side, you call the script and provide the username as non encrypted and your password as a sha1 hash, rehashed with a random salt (sha1(sha1(pass)+salt) (the salt is stored in the user session on server side)
- The script would then compared the provided hash with db password hash rehashed with session salt

The improvement is that the attacker must try to brute force two sha1 passwords consecutivaly and must provide a valid token to perform the login action. Plus if you use as salt a string using hex char of a variable even length, it will make the job harder for the attacker to recognised that the value bruteforced by the second hash is a sha1 hash, and even if he know it's an sha1 he will have to test multiple case to try to find the right portion of the value that correspond to the hash.

Because of variable salt, a same password won't be the same if hashed:
Imagine the attacker sniffed a hash and know which password was used then sniff another hash that was made with the same password as the other, the attacker won't be able to know that the 2 password where the same( a little overkill but still usefull).

It is safer to store the password as hashed value, because if the attacker manage to dump your user table, he won't be able to use the passwords right away, he would have to bruteforce each of then.
Finally sha1 hash are safer than md5 (i tell you that because you used the md5 tag in your post)

The downside of this method is that passwords can't be reversed, so you won't be able to given them back to your users if they lost it. You will have to make them set a new one.

An hardcore way (still without using HTTPS), would be to encrypt your password and username with a strong cypher (like AES or 3DES) and use a secure key echange algorythm (like the [Diffie Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) one) to exchange a random shared key.

This method won't block tampering, but will screw the attacker, because he won't be able to decrypt the value (assuming he only is sniffing the network). The key is random and never hardcoded in any of your application, so even if someone reverse your client, he won't be able to retreive a key.
I would still recommend to store your password value has hash.

An extreme way would be to merge the 2 methods but would be completly overkill.

Hope this will give you ideas

Comment: But why do all this when the problem can be securely and easily solved using HTTPS?

Comment: Because there are sometimes you don't want to use https ( https was what i meant by SSL) or can't use it (eg: you rent a webspace that do not allow https). https require ceritificates, and in case you don't want to pay for signed certificate and the application runs in a common browser you will have an ugly message telling you to accept a self signed ceritificate. Using an alternate way allow you to avoid this case. But in the case you use a custom client and https can be activated on server side, i totally agree that you should go with https instead of implementing your own security method.

Comment: Thank you this gave some ideas and pointed me in the right direction! BTW I don't use md5 on mt database, but along my original line of thinking the first hash would need to be reversible.

Comment: Glad i could help you. FYI md5 hash is not a reversible (in fact no hash is reversible), it just have a low security and collision avoidment than others. Which means it could be broken more easily than other (using rainbow tables for example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach isn't whether you are using encrpyted passwords and usernames in the URL or not. If the user authenticates by sending the encrpyted strings to you, then I as an attacker can still sniff out those hashes, pass them to your application and authenticate. This is unless then, that you do some public key/private key exchange before hand, but that is just reimplementing HTTPS, so you might as well just use HTTPS.

What you should do is to send the request using POST over HTTPS.

- POST: So that the authentication details will not be in the URL and show up in logs and referrer URLs.
- HTTPS so that the content of the whole request is fully encrypted and can only be decrypted by the client application and the server side.

Answer (score 0):

encryption with Javascript from client to server only prevent from non SSL posting fails.
I think you must use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) instead of this type encryption .

Answer (score 0):

Update:
You could add your own secret key in both scripts.